# Python pandas to_datetime works inconsistently: Why are month and day mixed up?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

With the python pandas package I run

```
pd.to_datetime("23.01.2019 06:50:59")
```

and get the expected result of

```
Timestamp('2019-01-23 06:50:59')
```

However, when running

```
pd.to_datetime("11.01.2019 18:34:39")
```

day and month are mixed up and I get

```
Timestamp('2019-11-01 18:34:39')
```

Expected was: `Timestamp('2019-01-11 18:34:39')`

Any ideas about why this happens and how to avoid it?
Thanks!

Comment: To be certain you should always specify the time format. Unless it's ISO 8601.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is possible use parameter `dayfirst=True`:

```
print (pd.to_datetime("11.01.2019 18:34:39", dayfirst=True))
2019-01-11 18:34:39
```

Generaly solution is with specify format of datetimes:

```
print (pd.to_datetime("11.01.2019 18:34:39", format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'))
2019-01-11 18:34:39
```

> Why are month and day mixed up?

Because pandas try guess format and `MMDDYYYY` have more priority like `DDMMYYY`.

Comment: I'll go with the format parameter then. To be honest, I just didn't understand what it was doing as I thought it is used to specify the output (not the input) format. Thanks!